# atop + what define when /var/log/atop/atop_log should be created

Tags: rhel, logs, atop

today I installed the atop tool ( before two hours )
in order to trace the OS performance

```
 rpm -i atop-2.3.0-8.el7.x86_64.rpm

 atop -V
Version: 2.3.0 - 2017/03/25 09:59:59     <gerlof.langeveld@atoptool.nl>
```

when we try to find the logs under

```
 ls -ltr /var/log/atop/
total 0
```

we do not see logs

my question - what is defined when the logs creation

and how to force the logs creation after for example one hour

note-  in order to trigger the atop it is necessary to perform the following steps :

```
   systemctl enable application.service

   systemctl  start atop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man`

> When atop is installed, the script atop.daily is stored in the /etc/atop directory.  This scripts takes care that atop is activated every day at midnight  to  write
>          compressed binary data to the file /var/log/atop/atop_YYYYMMDD with an interval of 10 minutes.
>          Furthermore the script removes all raw files which are older than four weeks.
>          The script is activated via the cron daemon using the file /etc/cron.d/atop with the contents
>
> ```
>          0 0 * * * root /etc/atop/atop.daily
> ```

If you have installed from epel the script path will be `/etc/sysconfig/atop`

Dont forget to start the service.

```
[root@testserver atop]# pwd
/var/log/atop
[root@testserver atop]# ls
atop_20180829  atop.log
```

Comment: so if it will create the log "activated every day at midnight to write compressed binary data" , but is it possible to force it to create it immediately ?  and not to wait when  midnight

Comment: @yael i hope it purely depends on cron schedule time ....

Comment: I change the file /etc/cron.d/atop  to * * * * * root systemctl try-restart atop , so it will create it every min  , but log not created under /var/log/atop  , why?

Comment: @yael `*/01 * * * * root PATH` for every min

Comment: ok I change it , lets see what happens -:)

Comment: still no files under /var/log/atop , what is wrong here ?

Comment: I also run it manual "root systemctl try-restart atop" but no files creation under /var/log/atop

Comment: @yael can checked the service status

Comment: yes we enable the service and start it now we see the files , but I have another question , can we limit the files for example only to 5 , because this files can be with huge size

Comment: @yael i hope that we can achieve with regular logrotate

Comment: last quotation - if for example we want get the file atop_20180829 from remote machine and put it on my machine , can we use my atop in spite the file was created on remote machine ?

Comment: you mean you need to check it ?